# Zend Framework 2 real world application file structure

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have just started out with ZF2 and i am very confused with Zend Skeleton Application.
In current situation URl looks like:

```
http://localhost/zf2/public/
```

And for a module named **Application** it looks like:

```
http://localhost/zf2/public/Application/
```

and the actions goes after the module name.
i want to create a CMS with ***admin panel*** and ***users panel***.
And that's why I want my URL for users to be like:

```
http://localhost/zf2
```

and for admin like:

```
http://localhost/zf2/admin/Module Name/Actions
```

So, my question is, How am i supposed to create URL like this?

Comment: Have you tried it using the router?. Don't know about zf2 but this can certainly be done through zend routers in zf1??

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html provides the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url examples look like you are confusing the public directory and the controller routes. You should usually not have a url like this:

```
http://localhost/zf2/public/
```

Instead you should generally be using a vhost. There are numerous ways to do this, but generally it boils down to either a custom port or a custom hosts entry if you want a named vhost. Then your url to public will look like one of these two options:

```
http://localhost:9000/
```

or

```
http://myapp.local/
```

If you are using PHP 5.4, in your development environment, by far the easiest way to start a host is to use the PHP 5.4 built-in server. You start that up like this on the command line from your project root (this makes the public directory the web root of the temporary web server on port 9000 of your localhost):

```
php -S localhost:9000 -t public
```

Once you have your web server configuration sorted out, the Skeleton app will automatically interpret your url routes (by default) like this:

```
http://localhost:9000/some-module/some-controller/some-action
```

If you want to put in the full literal path the the default indexAction on the IndexController in the Skeleton app, it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:9000/application/index/index
```